# Converting .py to .exe file using pyinstaller

Tags: python

So I used `pyinstaller` to convert `.py` files to `.exe`. What I write in the command prompt is

```
pyinstaller -F -w -i icon.ico main.py
```

and it works and all but when I delete the icon and other dependencies it gives an error.

So does anyone know how can convert all my files into one `.exe` file, because `-F` and `--onefile` don't work for me?

Comment: You should not delete icon and dependency files. PyInstaller just adds python interpreter + used libraries to the final exe file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--icon = icon.ico` instead of `-i`.